# flex and bison issue for real numbers

Tags: flex-lexer

I have been using flex and bison for making a small calculator. My files are the following:

bisonFile.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token EOL
%%
calclist: /* nothing */
| calclist exp EOL { printf("= %d\n", $2); }
;
exp: factor
| exp ADD factor { $$ = $1 + $3; }
| exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
;
factor: term
| factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
| factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
;
term: NUMBER
| ABS term { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; }
;
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
yyparse();
}
yyerror(char *s)
{
fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

flexFile.l

```
%{
# include "f5.tab.h"
int yylval;
%}
/* reconocimiento de tokens e impresion */
%{
int yylval;
%}
%option noyywrap
%%
"+" { return ADD; }
"-" { return SUB; }
"*" { return MUL; }
"/" { return DIV; }
"|" { return ABS; }
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)? { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }   //part added
\n { return EOL; }
[ \t] { /* ignore whitespace */ }
. { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

My program works fine with integer numbers, and it also recognizes real numbers, but the problem is that when I print the results of an operation it always return the answer as an integer number. Why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your use of atoi in the production converts the string to an integer.
Using atof will convert it to a floating point number.
If you want to separate the two, you'll need to change the matching rule for integers, and add one for floating point.

Comment: I have tried that also, and still prints the answer as an integer

Answer (score 0):

Change `"%d"` → `"%f"` in the file “bisonFile.y”. This uses a floating point format for printing the result. The fixed line should read:

```
| calclist exp EOL { printf("= %f\n", $2); }
```

In the file “flexFile.l” remove **both** definitions `int yylval`. bison outputs

```
YYSTYPE yylval;
```

automatically. `YYSTYPE` is the type of the semantic values. Because you want a floating point calculator, this shall be `double`. Note that `YYSTYPE` defaults to `int`. To change that, `YYSTYPE` must be defined when compiling the C-codes (from bison and flex) (see below).

Finally, as already stated by MIS, replace `atoi()` → `atof()`. The edited line in flexFile.l should read:

```
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)? { yylval = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
```

For a novice the dependencies between flex and bison sources might be confusing. A minimal Makefile documents how the example can be compiled. Line 2 sets the semantic type for the scanner and the parser consistently:

```
calc:               calc.o l.o
calc.o l.o:         CFLAGS+=-DYYSTYPE=double
l.o:                l.c f5.tab.h
calc.c f5.tab.h:    bisonFile.y
                    bison -o $@ --defines=f5.tab.h $^
l.c:                flexFile.l f5.tab.h
                    flex -o $@ $^
clean::
                    $(RM) calc calc.o calc.c f5.tab.h l.o l.c
```

That’ll do the trick.

Comment: You should remove (both) declarations of `yylval`. It is defined in the bison generated C file and declared `extern` in the generated bison header, so an explicit declaration is redundant and two of them doubly so.

Comment: @rici: Thanks. That’s cleaner. I’ll rework my answer.